# smileRandomForest classification "Error: classification: Computed value is too large."

Tags: google-earth-engine

The problem is that cannot compute the AGB，GEE reports all the time the same error:

> "Error: Image.sample: Computed value is too large."

```
var roi=table.geometry();
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MCD43A4')
                  .filterBounds(roi).filterDate('2001-01-01', '2001-01-02')
                  .select([
  'Nadir_Reflectance_Band1', 'Nadir_Reflectance_Band2',
  'Nadir_Reflectance_Band3','Nadir_Reflectance_Band4',
  'Nadir_Reflectance_Band5','Nadir_Reflectance_Band6',
  'Nadir_Reflectance_Band7'
],['b1','b2','b3','b4','b5','b6','b7'])
                  .map(function(image){var image1=image.clip(roi);return image1})
var dataset2=dataset.map(function(image){
  var image0=image.select('b1').rename('b1');
  var band2=image.select('b2').rename('b2');
  var band3=image.select('b3').rename('b3');
  var band4=image.select('b4').rename('b4');
  var band5=image.select('b5').rename('b5');
  var band6=image.select('b6').rename('b6');
  var band7=image.select('b7').rename('b7');
  var band8=image3.select('b1').rename('b8');
 return image0.addBands(band2).addBands(band3).addBands(band4).addBands(band5).addBands(band6).addBands(band7).addBands(band8);
})
var image_AGB=image.select('b1').expression('b1*1000',
{
  'b1':image.select('b1').rename('b1')
  }).toInt32().rename('b9');
print('AGB_sample',image_AGB)
var image_AGB_Ref=image2.addBands(image_AGB);
print('AGB_Ref',image_AGB_Ref);
var training = image_AGB_Ref.sample({
  numPixels: 5000,
  seed: 0
});
print('sample',training);
/* RandomForest*/
var RF=ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(20)
.train({
  features: training,
  classProperty:'b9',
  inputProperties:['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5', 'b6', 'b7','b8']
});
print('RF',RF);
var AGB_set=dataset2.map(function(image){
  var AGB=image.select(['b1','b2','b3','b4','b5','b6','b7','b8']).classify(RF).rename('AGB');
  return AGB});
//image.addBands(AGB)
var AGB_list=AGB_set.toList(50);
print('AGB_list',AGB_list);
var AGB_list_size= AGB_list.size().getInfo();
for(var i=0; i<AGB_list_size;i = i+1)
{
  var image = ee.Image(AGB_list.get(i));
  var product_ID=ee.String(image.get('system:index'))
//  print(image)
  Export.image.toDrive(
    {image:image,
    description:product_ID.getInfo(),
    folder: 'AGB',
    fileNamePrefix:product_ID.getInfo(),
    crs:'EPSG:4326',
    region: roi,
    scale:500,
    maxPixels:1e13}
    )
}
```